# How to implement a "reverse" BFS algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

[image]I'm playing a game with the following rules:
There is a map (with walls), some coins (randomly generated in the map) and a Minotaur. The goal is to grab as many coins as possible without the minotaur killing you. I have implemented a BFS to find coins and move towards them, but my character keeps dying to the minotaur, because i don t know how to make an efficient "run away" algorithm.

What would be the best solution to find the path that runs away from the minotaur as fast as possible (without colliding with walls)

The pseudo code would look somewhat like this:

```
*if(minotaur_is_close) run_away*

*else find_coins*
```

Edit: Added picture of the starting round of randomly generated map (green tiles are walkable, grey ones are walls, blue is character, red is Minotaur, orange are coins)

Comment: Could you assign a high negative “coin” value to the Minotaur?

Comment: Can you post what your map looks like?

Comment: If the minotaur is within 10 squares, run BFS to find the path to the closest point that is >= 15 squares away from the minotaur.

Comment: Is "Minoutaur" an intended pun between "Minotaur" and "minou" (French for "kitty")?

Comment: More importantly, is the character faster than the Minotaur? If not, you don't just need to run "away", but you need to run "in circles" around the walls